# String output -> System.out.println break down

Tags: java, string

I am trying to break down some code so that i can better understand it.
This is a segment of a String method

```
public String randomGame() {

     String output = "There were " + Count + " wars\n";
     output += player1.getName() + " won " + player1.win() + " cards and " + player1.getTheory() + " theory(s)\n";
     output += player2.getName() + " won " + player2.win() + " cards and " + player2.getTheory() + " theory(s)\n";


     if(player1.winPerTurn() > player2.winPerTurn()){
        output += "Winner: " + player1.getName();
     } 
     else {
        output += "Winner: " + player2.getName();
     }

     return output;
  }
```

Personally i am not comfortable with these kind of outputs.
I already know what it prints out,
my question is. Is it possible for me to somehow reformat this logic
in a system.out.print kind of form?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `in a system.out.print kind of form` ?

Comment: mm Basically, If i were to "re write" this code,
How would i rewrite it where i can use System.out.print

Comment: @libik That is actually kind of what i am trying to get at.
I am just more comfortable running System.out.print tests

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Is it possible for me to somehow reformat this logic in a system.out.print kind of form?

but if your goal is to better understand what happens in your code, you could use a debugger to go through your code step-by-step and see which variable holds which value.

//EDIT :

See [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) for a tutorial on howto use the debugger in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can use %s to modify information, so the first output

```
String output = String.format("There were %s wars\n", Count);
```

And in a best practice method.

```
private static final String WARS_STRING = "There were %s wars\n";

//in some code
String output = String.format(WARS_STRING, Count);
```

---

There is another option to build Strings, using the previous, that is using StringBuilder to concatenate them all.

```
private static final String WARS_STRING = "There were %s wars\n";
private static final String WON = "%s won %s cards and %s theory(s)\n";

//in some code
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(String.format(WARS_STRING, Count));
builder.append(String.format(WON, player2.win(), player1.win(),player1.getTheory()));
builder.append(String.format(WON, player1.win(), player2.win(),player2.getTheory()));
return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

does it help:

```
private void displayPlayerInfo(Player player)
{
    System.out.println(player.getName() + " won " + player.win() + " cards and " + player.getTheory() + " theory(s)");
}

public void randomGame() {
    System.out.println("There were " + Count + " wars");
    displayPlayerInfo(player1);
    displayPlayerInfo(player2);
    System.out.println("Winner: " + (player1.winPerTurn() > player2.winPerTurn()? player1.getName(): player2.getName()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off printing it directly is that is all you are going to do with the output.  But are the win and winPerTurn methods simple getters?  The should be named as such.

if so

```
public void randomGame() {

 System.out.print ("There were " + Count + " wars\n");
 System.out.print (player1.getName() + " won " + player1.win() + " cards and " + player1.getTheory() + " theory(s)\n");
 System.out.print (player2.getName() + " won " + player2.win() + " cards and " + player2.getTheory() + " theory(s)\n");


 if(player1.winPerTurn() > player2.winPerTurn()){
    System.out.println ("Winner: " + player1.getName());
 } 
 else {
    System.out.println (output += "Winner: " + player2.getName());
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
public void randomGame() {
    System.out.println("There were " + Count + " wars");
    System.out.println(player1.getName() + " won " + player1.win() + " cards and " + player1.getTheory() + " theory(s)");
    System.out.println(player2.getName() + " won " + player2.win() + " cards and " + player2.getTheory() + " theory(s)");
    System.out.println("Winner: " + (player1.winPerTurn() > player2.winPerTurn()? player1.getName(): player2.getName()));
}
```